# Using CSS, how do you change the color for the hover state on a word that has a couple of letters colored differently?

Tags: html, css

[Link appearance before and during hover state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGV4D.png)

I have a link where the first and last letter are the color red, and the letters in between are black. This is how the link should look, regardless of whether it has been visited or not. However, the **entire** word for that link should change to the color green for the hover state. Can this be accomplished with CSS?

```
<h1 id="mainLogo">
    <a class="redLetters" href="index.html" title="Link">L</a>
    <a id="Logo" href="index.html" title="Link"><nobr> i n </a>
    <a class="redLetters" href="index.html" title="Link">k</a>
</h1>
```

My [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zLoaznes)

Comment: My fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/zLoaznes/

Answer (score 3):

You just place the `:hover` on the containing element:

```css
#Logo {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.redLetters {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#mainLogo:hover a {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<header role="banner" id="mainHeader">
  <h1 id="mainLogo">
    <a class="redLetters" href="index.html" title="Link">L</a>
    <a id="Logo" href="index.html" title="Link"><nobr> i n </nobr></a>
    <a class="redLetters" href="index.html" title="Link">k</a>
  </h1>
</header>
```

Relevant part:

```
#mainLogo:hover a {
  color: green;
}
```

You had some minor `HTML` markup errors. Here's your *fixed* [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/zLoaznes/2/).

---

As a sidenote, you should not create three different links for each letter. If a user clicks between the letters they will miss the link and you don't want that. You should create only one link and, inside it, color the desired letters using a span, when not hovered.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/zLoaznes/13/) is what I am talking about.

Comment: I like your solution very much, Andrei, it's concise. I have it working the way I want to see it in jsfiddle - 
https://jsfiddle.net/zLoaznes/14/
However, I am hounded by the underlining once I make the changes in my IDE and refresh the browser. I copied the code exactly, and it's driving me crazy!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the request. Is the `text-decoration` not applying in your environment? If so, right-click and inspect element, look at the current `tex-decoration` applying and where it is coming from. After that, all you need to do is make your selector stronger than the one applying. Another cause might be your CSS is not 100% valid. Sometimes not finishing a rule affects the next ones (as the browser still looks for the ending bracket of the previous rule). Use an online validator and pay close attention to details.

Comment: Your question reminded me of one of the best designed logos I know. Here's an [animated CSS](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/zLoaznes/22/) version of it.

Comment: Fixed the underlining issue, thanks for the fiddle of the animated logo. Very clever how that was accomplished! I was hoping there was a way to do that without resorting to Java. Very cool!

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
 h1:hover a, h1:hover nobr{
     color:green;
 }
```

It is important that you respect the specificity defined by your HTML. SInce you have the inner letters in a `<nobr>` adding this specificity ensures they are also inheriting the hover behavior and not just when you hover the outside letter ;)

See your [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/zLoaznes/11/)

Answer (score 0):

```
#Logo {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.redLetters {
    color: red;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#mainLogo:hover *{
    color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed your markup a bit, so that you only have one link around your text. Then I used spans to style your letters.

Now when you hover over the link you can change the color of the link and the child `span`s

```css
#Logo {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.redLetters {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover,
a:hover span {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<header role="banner" id="mainHeader">
  <h1 id="mainLogo">
    <a href="index.html" title="Link">
      <span class="redLetters">L</span>
      i n
      <span class="redLetters" href="index.html" title="Link">k</span>
    </a>
  </h1>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
#mainLogo:hover a {
   color: green;
}
```

On hover, this will cause the entire word to be green.

Here's a [working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/5qhndt87/1/).

Comment: Initially I thought the same, then I hovered over the outside letters and the center ones didn't change. I'm not sure if the OP meant to have a nobr tag in there or not, but that was the culprit. Maybe you got to a fiddle version that had the nobr tag removed and/or replaced by a span tag

Comment: Yeah, my fiddle worked fine and the entire word changed color.

Answer (score 0):

You have separated the word in 3 links and the css targets every single one of them separately.

You could target all 3 with `#mainLogo:hover a`, or better yet - not use 3 links, but one with a different colored `span` like so http://jsfiddle.net/zLoaznes/12/